# How to create a batch script to find and replace pages within multiple documents

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have created several Word Templates and Forms (over 100).  If any form in a template changes, all like forms in other templates must be updated as well. For example, if another field is added to the form, then I need to update 100 templates with this same added field. So, let's say the templates are saved according to client:

```
Q://Master Templates/Client Name/Client Template
```

(Note, the client template may have about 30 or more pages - like a contract and the form might be page 29 in this client, but another client may have 60 pages and the form might be page 20).

Then, there is another folder where the form is a standalone form, or part of a group of forms that are used together. Example:

```
Q://Master forms/Group Forms
Q://Master forms/Standalone Forms
```

First question: would it make sense to have a batch script that finds the form in each template or each folder; and then should the script find add replace the extra field, or does it make more sense to replace the entire form in the templates?

Second question: how would / could I do this? Is there a way to write the script to replace the form in each location based on the example above?

Third question: what types of security risks or problems such a batch script can create for an enterprise-wide network?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add, I know "NOTHING" about batch scripting and if I used incorrect terminology, I do apologize.  Maybe there I am referring to a batch file verses script.

Comment: Batch has a pretty hard time interacting with things that aren't text files. Throw forms into the mix and it's pretty much impossible without seriously complex, nasty code. I think VBA would be a better fit for this situation.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  User4317867 was kind enough to provide a VBA suggestion. I am going to test that out and see if it works.  My only concern is figuring out how to make sure the right changes are made the the right form. Let's say in one template that encompases 12 forms, I need to creeate a change to form 7, on page 30 of the template/file.  But that same form might be on page 25 in another template, what would be the best way to approach. I am considering creating bookmarks, maybe, then writing VBA code that finds that bookmark then make the changes (?).  Lots to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best answer is to use the Developer ribbon in Word.  Within Word, File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Check the Developer item under Main Tabs.

Next, open one template needing changes and click Record Macro then make your changes.

Now you can open (In Windows Explorer, ctrl + click then right click to open multiple files) the other templates needing the changes and replay the macro to make those changes.

You could even record opening another document then just add the VBA code to open the other templates and play back the recorded macro to make the changes.

Here's the VBA to open a document in Word.

```
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\"
Documents.Open FileName:="My File.docx"
```

Now once you get at least something partial, post back and we can help refine that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I am going to try this on a grouop of test documents during the week. I will postback to advise how it works.

Comment: Sorry, no updates!  :(  Still working on it...trial and error.

Comment: One other option is to create a template document with no sensitive information and upload that to Dropbox or a similar site.  Then just outline what needs to be changed.